# How to open an application in Mac OS using Python

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I want to open an application like TextEdit or Firefox in Mac OS using Python and wait till the applications exits. I can't figure out exact command to open an app and wait.

Comment: I improved your formatting. Please edit in what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know how to do it in applescript, but you can do this by using the `/usr/bin/open` UNIX-level OS X command. This snippet will open TextEdit.app and block, waiting for it to quit before continuing:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/TextEdit.app"]
    )
```

Look at the open man page ([`man open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)) and the python [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Yeah using this code, even though I close textedit, the code is not exiting, it is still in blocking state

Comment: Did you close TextEdit, or did you *exit* TextEdit? Per the documentation, the `-W` switch tells open to wait for the program to exit.  And it worked in my testcase; the subprocess stopped blocking when I exited TextEdit.

Comment: Yeah I closed the application, but still it is blocking

Comment: You don't "close" and application in Mac. you "close" a document. You Quit an application - and when I did so - the above subprocess.call() command returned as expected. This suggestion works fine. However, on the next level - If I'm not waiting for the app to exit, how can I grab the "subprocess" object of the TextEdit, and not the "open" process???

Comment: on the Mac semantics, you can't "close" an application. You can only "close" a window of an application. The application remains running even with no open windows. The right semantics is "Quit" an application, which is a distinct action, available  from the application's menu in the menu-bar (the menu named after the application itself) its key-abbreviation is Command-Q

Answer (score 5):

You can open any application like this example

```
import os

os.system("open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app")
os.system("open /Applications/Todoist.app")
os.system("open /Applications/WhatsApp.app")
```

Comment: This won't work with native apps, e.g. `Dictionary.app` or `FaceTime.app`

Comment: This works just fine:

```os.system("open /System/Applications/FaceTime.app") ```

Answer (score 2):

AppleScript:

```
tell app "Whatever you want" to open
```

Call from Python

```
import os
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to open'""")
```

Comment: This is the error I see on Mac OS 11.1 (Python 3.9.6):
21:25: execution error: Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
256

Answer (score -1):

This works for me on Mac OS 11.1:

```
import os

os.system("open -a TextEdit")
print("Done and not blocking")
```

Comment: There is already an answer with `import os` and an `os.system(..)` by Arthur Correa, so I fail to see how this adds any value as a new answer.  Also, this doesn't actually answer what was asked in the OP!.

Comment: @user3439894 I was looking for an answer to a similar question: "how to open an Mac OS application from Python, but without blocking". My answer doesn't require a full path to the application and doesn't block.

Comment: RE: "but without blocking"" --  But that is not what the OP is wanting!  RE: "My answer doesn't require a full path to the application " --  Not enough to justify a separate answer, just comment on the existing answer.

Comment: It isn't 100% of what the original poster wanted but you never know. Maybe he changed his mind and wants a non-blocking way to open an application.

Answer (score -2):

You can close any app on osx (like Chrome or Safari) with this in python:

```
import os

os.system("pkill Chrome")
```