# Python multiprocessing without locking the parent process

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

OS:- Mac OSX

Python

I'm new to Multiprocessing with python. For my application, I want to open a new process from main and run it without locking the main process. for eg. I'm running process A and now i need to open a new application from A, lets call it process B. I want to open B in such a way that it does not blocks process A and still from Process i should be able to stop the process whenever i wish to.

Till now whatever code i have tried are basic and they lock the process A. and hence i'm unable to achieve it. Is there any workaround to do this ?

I read about fork and spawn but couldn't understand how can i use it to open an application. And i have tried threading also. But with no success. Can anyone tell me how can i do that ?

Currently I'm using subprocess.call() to open Mac Applications through Python.
It would be really helpful.

**EDIT :-**

[I tried the accepted answer of this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)
but to no avail. Because it would block the terminal and once we close the app manually it exits with output 0.

Also I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845242/how-to-open-an-application-in-mac-os-using-python). It would do the same. I want to make the the calling process not to be blocked by the called process.

while doing the same task in windows with os.system() gives me exactly what i want. But i don't know how can i do this in Mac.

EDIT 2: CODE

module 1:

```
import subprocess


def openCmd(name):

    subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/"+name+".app"])

def closeCmd(name):
    subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', 'tell "'+name+'" to quit'])
```

main module:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx
import opCl


speech_engine = pyttsx.init('nsss')
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

OPEN_COGNATES=['open']
CLOSE_COGNATES=['close']

def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()

re = sr.Recognizer()  

def listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        re.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)


        while True:
            speak("Say something!")
            print ">>",
            audio = re.listen(source)

            try:
                speak("now to recognise it,")
                value=re.recognize_google(audio)
                print  (value)
                speak("I heard you say {}".format(value))
                value=value.strip().split()
                name=" ".join(value[1:])
                if value[0] in OPEN_COGNATES:
                    speak("opening "+name)
                    opCl.openCmd(name)
                    pass
                elif value[0] in CLOSE_COGNATES:
                    speak("opening "+name)
                    opCl.closeCmd(name)
                    pass
                else:
                    pass


            except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                speak("Could not understand audio")
                print ('Could not understand audio')
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                speak("can't recognise what you said.")
                print ("can't recognise what you said")


if __name__=='__main__':
    listen()
```

Comment: @stovfl I edited the question. I hope now it helps.

Comment: i hope now it works @stovfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: it gave a traceback. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'leafpad'

As i wrote, **I can't** us `"/usr/bin/open"` and `osascript`, so my example uses `'leafpad'`.

Have you tried replacing `Popen([name])` with your
`Popen(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/"+name+".app"])`?

You must pass the same `command args` as you start it from the `command line`.
Read this: [launch-an-app-on-os-x-with-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308755/launch-an-app-on-os-x-with-command-line)

> Reread **[From Python » 3.6.1 Documentation subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)**  
> **Note**
> shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex cases:

---

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation**:
> subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, timeout=None)
> Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute

Your given `"/usr/bin/open"` and `osascript` didn't work for me.

[From Python » 3.6.1 Documentation subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)  
**NOWAIT example**, for instance:

```
import subprocess

def openCmd(name):
    subprocess.Popen([name])

def closeCmd(name):
    subprocess.Popen(['killall', name])
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        key = input('input 1=open, 0=cloes, q=quit:')
        if key == '1':
            openCmd(('leafpad'))
        if key == '0':
            closeCmd('leafpad')
        if key == 'q':
            break
```

**Note**: Killing a `process` can lead to data loos and or other problems.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***
I'm

Comment: it gave a traceback. 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'leafpad'`
event trying with safari didn't opened the application. i'm trying on python 3.6.1
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'safari'`

Comment: Thanx man. It worked now. But idk killall didn't worked. Instead `['osascript', '-e', 'tell application"'+name+'" to quit']` this worked. Thank you so much.